# How to change email input validator messages?

Tags: html, validation

I want to override validators of html5 email input with setCustomValidity.

But I'm having difficulty writing code to differentiate between three different messages. 
I can change Please fill in this field message but how can i change the other two messages.

- Please include an @ in the email address
- Please enter a part following @...

patternMismatch does not work.

```
var email = document.getElementById("email")

email.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
    if(this.validity.valueMissing){
        e.target.setCustomValidity("ایمیل خود را وارد کنید."); 
    } else if(this.validity.patternMismatch) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("U R DOIN IT WRONG!"); 
    } 
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this in your HTML code, you wont need `<script>`

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="ایمیل شما" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ایمیل وارد شده مشکل دارد!')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

Comment: this doesn't change the other two messages